# How Can I Use The "GeckoInputElement "

Tags: c#, gecko

I am making use of the GeckoWebbrowser control in a C# Windows forms app environment.

Hi, i have noticed everywhere on this forum users using the 'GeckoInputElement' and i have tried using it myself and C# does not recognise it, is there something i have missed on installation if so what and what can i do to use this, if not how can i use this in C#.

I have already tried just typing it in, but it just shows an error could not be found.

`GeckoInputElement`

Comment: See this is what i am not sure about i have just download the ell of Skybound.Gecko, and im not sure how to access it or call it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct using clauses. You need 
`using Gecko.DOM;`

or in your code try:

`Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement myInputEle = //blah blah`

Let me know if this helps